# Plotting 3-D Matrix *values* in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, matrix, plot

I have a 3D Matrix M(256x256x136) and each index(i,j,k) in M has a gray level value in it. I am interested in displaying M in some sort of a 3D plot in MATLAB, but am unable to do so. I cannot use plot3 because plot3 is for plotting points, not the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to plot the 3D point cloud with `i`,`j`, and `k` as 3D coordinates and the gray level as the point value.

I would suggest using [`scatter3`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for a volume renderer. For Matlab, you could try this one: [Volume Render from Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19155-volume-render)

An `isosurface` plot might be useful as well.