# Matlab 3D Matrix Plot

Tags: matlab, 3d, matrix, plot, velocity

Ive created a 3d matrix in MATLAB. The values of the matrix are the velocity at that point in a rectangular section. I would like a plot with colours showing the values at each position, is this possible?

Phrasing this another way, I have a matrix of size 100x100x200. Id like a graph that has 100x100x200 points and the colour of each of those points is related to its value.

Comment: You should definitely accept the answer should it have solved your problem.

Answer (score 11):

This question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302484/plotting-3-d-matrix-values-in-matlab/9302690#9302690). You might want to check it out.

**UPDATE:**

Suppose you have a 3D matrix **A**:

```
A = rand(100,100,200);
```

You want to plot each entry of **A** mapped to a color at its 3D coordinates. First generate the coordinates:

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:100,1:100,1:200);
```

Now you are ready to use `scatter3`:

```
scatter3(x(:),y(:),z(:),5,A(:))
```

Here the `:` indexing vectorizes the coordinates column-wise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks useful for the scatter3 function, however how do I put my values into it if my matrix is currently the dimensions posted above?

Comment: @user1045280: I updated my answer to reflect your comment.