# 3d plots in matlab based on a matrix

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matlab 3D Matrix Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396096/matlab-3d-matrix-plot)

I have a matrix in matlab that I want to plot as a 3D figure. 
Suppose the matrix looks like the following:

> A=[4 7 8; 2 3 9 ]

This actually means the following data points in x,y,z plane

> (1,1,4) (1,2,7) (1,3,8) (2,1,2) (2,2,3) (2,3,9)

I want to plot these values on a 3D graph.

How can I do that?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396096/matlab-3d-matrix-plot)

Comment: You can use surf(A) to plot your 2D matrix. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827934/3d-plotting-of-a-2d-matrix-in-matlab/19742713#19742713

Answer (score 2):

The function to use is [`surf(A)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html)
This will plot your points from x = 1:2 and y = 1:3