# 3d plotting of a 2d matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an MxN matrix, Z, and some variable h.  This matrix represents the points to a solution of a function f(x,y).  h is the spacing between points.  For instance:

```
Z(x/h,y/h) = (some value in the Z direction), where x and y are some multiple of h
```

The domain is from 0 to M*h and the range is from 0 to N*h.  I would like to make a 3d representation of the solution defined by the matrix.  The graph should be similar to what is produced using the pdetool.  How do I do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `surf` or `bar3`.

Here is the documentation:

surf: 
http://www.mathworks.fr/help/matlab/ref/surf.html;jsessionid=c680a6b29a1fa8ff47c120353c12

[image]

bar3:
http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html
[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I think surf is what I am wanting.  Is there a way to use the surf command and define a non-rectangular domain?  Basically I have a region of the matrix that I do not want to plot.

Comment: as described in the documentation, you can use `surf(X,Y,Z)` to specify the `(X,Y)` position of each `Z`. This can be used to have holes in your stuff. I cannot give more details without more explanation about your `holes`. Maybe ask a separate question.

Comment: yeah but if I set X to something like [0,h,2h,2h,...] and Y similarly, how does that produce holes?  It says I can specify X and Y as a matrix but I dont understand how that would work.  I will ask in a separate question.

Comment: X and Y should have the same size than Z

Comment: yeah but what is the (x,y) coordinate for a point in Z that should not be graphed?  I cant make it (0,0) or something cause all the Z points will just go to (0,0).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of using `surf` to plot a 2D matrix in Matlab.

**Code:**

```
x_offset = [78, 216, 150, 342, 258, 336;
            168, 174, 174, 222, 150, 246;
            36, 180, 54, 138, 138, 198;
            60, -72, 90, 66, 114, 36;
            -90, -108, -60, 12, 54, -24;
            -42, -78, -138, -42, -12, -114;
            -108, -30, -108, -66, -156, -114;
            -66, -114, -114, -84, -138, -96];
figure(1), surf(x_offset);
xlabel('X'), ylabel('Y'), title('X-offset Error Distribution');
```

**Output:**

[image]