# How to search through arrays to find a match

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a `4x~50,000 array`, where the first `3 rows` hold the `x y z coordinates`, then some corresponding values of a given location.

i.e.,

```
row 1 |  1   2   3   4   5   1...
row 2 |  1   1   1   1   1   1...
row 3 |  0   0   0   0   0   1...
row 4 | 0.7 0.2 1.0 0.3 0.3 0.5
```

I want to rearrange this data into a `3D array`, to plot this data in fMRI style
for example,

```
 3Darray(1,1,0) = 0.7 
 3Darray(2,1,0) = 0.2
 3Darray(3,1,0) = 1.0
```

.
.
.

I'm having trouble going through the rows simultaneously to match all three `x,y,z, values`.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thank you,

Regards,

P

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302484/plotting-3-d-matrix-values-in-matlab. Also, you could consider using one of the libraries that I assume are still available (though I haven't done fMRI work in a few years), like bvqxtools, AFNI for Matlab, or SPM.

Comment: Be aware that Matlab uses one-based indexing, not zero-based indexing, so you can't do `3Darray(1,1,0)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `sub2ind`! Here's a dummy array I made for testing,

```
%// example array
array=[1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
    1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3
    rand(1,10)]
```

And the code:

```
n=max(array(1:3,:),[],2).'; %// get size of final array
m=zeros(n); %// make an array of zeros of that size
ind=sub2ind(n,array(1,:),array(2,:),array(3,:)); %// get linear indices of elements
m(ind)=array(4,:); %// put elements into the array
```